# How to use custom maps images in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mapkit

I've searching about using custom maps (for example: a campus university map) in the iPhone App, using coordinates to get my actual position, etc.

I've found one way to do that:
- Using de google code project: "Route-me" with the OpenStreetMap and map2sqlite.

The question is: ¿How I can put my own map layer (the campus university map, PNG file) into the World map to execute map2sqlite for getting the DB in the "route-me" project.

I've investigated into the OpenStreetMap site, but I didn't found the way to do that, only to add paths into the map, but not other image maps (tiles).

Thank you so much!
Javier.

Comment: If I were you I would choose a different approach (yet I have never done this): Take the image with the campus and add it to a UIScrollView, then go out with a GPS handset (eg. your iPhone) and get the coordinates of a point on your campus map (preferably an edge). Afterwards you can easily create your own coordinate system for within the campus map and with some math you just transform the global coordinates into your local. You can indicate the user's location with a pin whose position you just update when the coordinates update. Probably not terribly easy, yet it sounds doable to me :)

Comment: Good approach! I'll try it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MapTiler](http://www.maptiler.org/) is your friend, you will also need this little script to change tiles number and then pass everything to map2sqlite

```
for I in `find . -type f -maxdepth 3 -mindepth 2 -name *.png` 
    do OLDNAME=`basename $I .png` 
    DIRNAME=`dirname $I` 
    SEP1=${I#./} 
    SEP2=${SEP1%%/*} 
    NEWNAME=$((2**$SEP2-$OLDNAME-1)) 
    mv "$I" "$DIRNAME"/"$NEWNAME.png" 
done
```

then you can also compress the png images with [pngcrush](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmt/files/pngcrush/)